# SQL Server not executing SqlExecuteReader

Tags: c#, sql-server, ado.net

I'm stumped, I have been trying to execute this and nothing happens. I know that the code reaches this point but it doesn't matter if I put gibberish in the SQL statement, it doesn't throw an error.

```
protected string checkLaptopStatus(String cardID)
{
    String ConnString = GetConnectSQLServer();
    String currentStatus = "";
    int i = 0;
   
    using (SqlConnection m_dbConnection = new SqlConnection(ConnString))
    {
        String sql = "SELECT laptopStatus FROM tblDevices WHERE cardID = " + cardID + "'";
        m_dbConnection.Open();

        // CODE REACHES THIS POINT BUT NEVER PASSES THIS ?
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, m_dbConnection))
        {
            using (SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
            {
                while (dr.Read())
                {
                    currentStatus = Convert.ToString(dr["laptopStatus"]);
                    i++;
                }
            }
        }
    }
   
   return currentStatus;    
}
```

Comment: Your query is invalid anyways. You should not creat query with string concatenation but use parameterized queries to prevent SQL injection and syntactic problems (you are missing the opening quote for your string parameter)

Comment: And you don't have any exception handling. Add some, and see if there is a exception thrown. There is no possibility that the runtime just stops n the middle of your code.

Comment: this isn't an sql question

Comment: I added a try block but how do I catch the error number to give me an idea?

Comment: There is no error number. That was a VB thing that has (thankfully) been mostly dead since 2001. Modern languages have exceptions in a catch block. You must `catch` the exception. You will usually then also look at the exception's `.Message` property.

Comment: I added a catch and just redirected somewhere and it does but not sure how to figure out what went wrong. I will change it to parameter but just want to know what actually went wrong in the first place.

Comment: `catch (Exception ex) { Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);}` or `catch (Exception ex) { MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);}` or `catch (Exception ex) { Response.Write(ex.Message);}` etc... depending on what platform you're using.

Comment: Thank you so much Joel, that gave me the error. I'll re write the code to parameter and update.

Answer (score 1):

Changed the code as advised and used the exception error message to find out what went wrong. thanks Joel for being kind and helping.

```
  protected void SQLReaderLaptops(string cardID)
{

    String ConnString = GetConnectSQLServer();
    int i = 0;   
    String todaysDate = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy'-'MM'-'dd");
    String laptopID = "";
    
    try { 
    using (SqlConnection m_dbConnection = new SqlConnection(ConnString))
    {      
        String sql = "Select laptopID From tblDevices WHERE cardID= @cardID";
        
        m_dbConnection.Open();
       

        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, m_dbConnection))
        {
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cardID", cardID);

            using (SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
            {
                while (dr.Read())
                {
                  
                    laptopID = Convert.ToString(dr["laptopID"]);
                    i++;
                   
                }
            }
        }
    }
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        //CAUGHT THE ISSUE HERE AND FOUND IT WAS A BAD COLUMN NAME
    }
```